# Mapreduce Job to find count of word frequencies in python

Tags: python, mapreduce, word-count

I have a large dataset of words and i have to calculate the count of word frequencies. To be more specific, lets say that i have the words (be,to,the,the,now,now,now,see,see,see). The word frequencies are

be: 1, 
to: 1, 
the: 2, 
now: 3, 
see: 3

I want to calculate the frequency count, so my output would be:

1: 2

2: 1

3: 2

Can this be done in one mapreduce procedure or do i need to create 1 mapreduce job to calculate the frequencies and another one to calculate the counts?

Comment: Added answer against your query. Kindly check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you anticipate, I believe you need two `mapreduce` programs.

- Count the number of words

This is going to be normal `wordcount` program. A nice tutorial is [here](http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2_--_Running_WordCount_in_Python).

- Count the frequencies.

It is pretty much going to be similar to another `wordcount` program. The steps would be:

1. Split the input line with `:` . e.g. split `now: 3` on `:` to have `now` and `3` (trimmed) element. It is similar to splitting each word on space in the word count.
2. Write the number part to the context against a value as `1` (as count 1) i.e. `3` in the step 1 should be output as Key -> `3`, Value -> `1` . It is same as output a `word` with count as `1` in `wordcount`
3. In the reducer just aggregate the count against each of the key. It is similar to aggregate counts in `wordcount`.